# How to load two vobs in a view where both vobs are in different registry and vob servers?

Tags: clearcase

I would like to know:

How to Load two vobs in two different views where both vobs are in different registry and vob servers in a single client windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

Different registry??? I dont think thats possible, because in the first place the View will not be the same across different registry.

Different VOB server in the same registry is not an issue, just load it normally.

Maybe I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

- to pick one registry server
- declare (`mktag` and `register`) the other vob from the other registry server in the first one
- make sure the global path of the other vob is accessible from your client and from the first vob server (Windows to Unix can work, with, for instance, Samba. But if your VOB server, the one that you pick, is a Unix one, it won't be able to access VOB managed by a *Windows* Vob server)

Note: the hard part is to `mktag` and `register` the other vob in your registry server: you cannot do it in command line, because it will try to modify some files in the vob storage (which your first registry server has no right to do)

You can however do it graphically:

- launch `ccadminconsole.msc`
- Select the 'Registry' section:

[image]

- create a new VOB object

[image]